# Помогите доработать алгоритм

Tags: c++, олимпиада

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код:

не знаю, как доработать алгоритм

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector <int> pairs;
    int count = 0, n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        pairs.push_back(temp);
    }
    sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());
    for(int cur = 0; cur < n; cur++){
        for(int sr = cur + 1; sr < n; sr++){
            if(max(pairs[cur], pairs[sr]) * 0.9 <= min(pairs[cur], pairs[sr])){
                count++;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << count;
}
```

Comment: Упорядочить файлы по размеру, далее смотреть, что в диапазон попадает...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Упорядочиваем массив по возрастанию.

```
[100, 102, 108, 109, 120, 125, 139]
```

Устанавливаем два указателя на его начало

```
 i j
[100, 102, 108, 109, 120, 125, 139]
```

теперь пока `a[i]` и `a[j]` находятся в пределах нужной разницы значений, прибавляем к результату количество пар, которые состовляет `a[j]` со всеми предыдущими значениями начиная с `a[i]`

```
 i j
[100, 102, 108, 109, 120, 125, 139]
```

плюс 0 пар

```
 i     j
[100, 102, 108, 109, 120, 125, 139]
```

плюс 1 пара (100, 102)

```
 i          j
[100, 102, 108, 109, 120, 125, 139]
```

плюс 2 пары (100, 108), (102, 108)

```
 i               j
[100, 102, 108, 109, 120, 125, 139]
```

плюс 3 пары (100, 109), (102, 109), (108, 109)

```
 i                    j
[100, 102, 108, 109, 120, 125, 139]
```

теперь разница между 100 и 120 слишком большая, сдвигаем `i`

```
      i               j
[100, 102, 108, 109, 120, 125, 139]
```

все еще большая

```
            i         j
[100, 102, 108, 109, 120, 125, 139]
```

еще плюс 2 пары (108, 120), (109, 120)
и т.д.

Получается алгоритм, работающий за линейное время (вместе с сортировкой - n*log n)

И еще я бы посоветовал сравнивать не `0.9*x` и `y`, а `9*x` и `10*y`, хотя в данной ситуации это роли не играет, при другом коэффициенте переход в вычисления с плавающей точкой может плохо сказаться на точности, благо диапазон значений ≤ 10<sup>8</sup> позволяет умножать на 10 без переполнения.

Comment: Можете поподробнее про "прибавляем к результату количество пар, которые состовляет a[j] со всеми предыдущими значениями начиная с a[i]", что это значит?

Comment: @Vitek_228_69 это значит, что добавляем к результату `j - i`. Разберите пример подробно, там вроде все наглядно. Я не хотел бы оставлять готовое решение.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую ваш алгоритм

Comment: на 8 тесте валится

Comment: @Vitek_228_69 Ну попробуйте все-таки избавиться от `0.9`, возможно на каком-то хитром значении теряется точность.

Comment: @Vitek_228_69 также возможно результат не помещается в `int`. Для массива с `100000` единицами это будет `4999950000`

Comment: поменял тип переменной count на long long, 100 баллов, спасибо, отметил ваш ответ

Answer (score 3):

зачем сделали много лишних действий?

решение в лоб выглядит как-то так:

```
// отсортировать размеры по возрастанию
sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());

// рассматривать 
for (int first = 0; first < n - 1; first ++){
    for (int second = first + 1; second < n; second ++){
        if first < second * 0.9
            break;

        count++;
    }
}
```

по идее дальше можно делать оптимизации

Comment: Всё равно по времени не проходит

Answer (score 2):

Сделал по совету @extrn
Получилось что-то такое

```
sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end());
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < n and j < n){
        while(j < n){
            if(pairs[i] < 0.9 * pairs[j]){
                i++;
            }
            else{
                count += (j - i);
                j++;
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Но на 8 тесте валится из-за неправильного ответа
Что здесь не так?